# RESTful HTTP OPTIONS request content

Tags: rest, http, http-response

I'm  having trouble determining what I might put in the body of a response to an `OPTIONS` request? are there conventions? standards? What do you put? do you just provide a list of other METHODS? should you give the representation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out *RESTful web services* By Leonard Richardson, Sam Ruby

Here's a [link](http://books.google.com/books?id=XUaErakHsoAC&lpg=PA98&ots=5jdlHplGqC&dq=RESTful%20web%20services%20OPTIONS%20method%20response&pg=PA98#v=onepage&q=RESTful%20web%20services%20OPTIONS%20method%20response&f=false) to page 98.  "There are no accepted standards."

The methods are part of the `ALLOW` header.  Not the body of the response.